# Can I reassign my Arduino Uno COM Port?

Tags: usb, uploading

The Arduino SW, under Tools, identifies my Uno as COM Port 3. However, COM Port 3 on my computer is in use by a chip set. My computer assigned COM Port 4 to my Arduino Uno.

Can I reassign my Uno to COM Port 4?

Edit: This question also applies to people who don't have administrative privileges. They do not have privileges to change the port via Windows Device Manager.

Answer (score 1):

If the Arduino IDE identified your Uno as COM Port 3, your computer most likely has already assigned COM Port 3 to your Uno. You can double check the port assignment in Device manager > Ports.

Comment: The issue is that I am not an admin and do not have the ability to re-assign ports on the computer. Therefore, I would like to Re-assign the port that Arduino is requesting. It can't be that hard.

Comment: This is not an answer. You can reassign the com port via the device manager... Assuming you are on a Windows PC

Answer (score 0):

You can change your COM Port number for a device by following these instructions:

http://plugable.com/2011/07/04/how-to-change-the-com-port-for-a-usb-serial-adapter-on-windows-7